# How to create redis workers dynamically without blocking the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, redis

I want to have a queue - worker management tool, that allows adding new queues, and registering jobs to those queues, with workers spawned to handle those jobs.

I have this code so far:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue, Retry, Worker


class WorkerPool: # TODO: find a better name
    def __init__(self):
        self._queues = {}
        self._workers = []
        self._redis_conn = Redis()

    def _get_queue(self, name):
        try:
            return self._queues[name]
        except KeyError:
            new_queue = Queue(name, connection=self._redis_conn)
            self._queues[name] = new_queue

            new_worker = Worker([new_queue], connection=self._redis_conn, name=name)
            new_worker.work() # Blocking :(

            return new_queue

    def add_job(self, queue, func, *func_args):
        q = self._get_queue(queue)
        job = q.enqueue(func, *func_args, retry=Retry(max=3))
        return job
```

As can be seen - the `work()` function blocks execution, while I want it to work in the background. I guess I can just create another thread here - and call `work()` from one thread, while the main thread returns the job, however, this seems a bit awkward to me. Is there a built-in `Redis` (or other known module) solution for this?

*PS, better names for my class are welcome :)*

---

This is my take on multiprocessing it (threading won't work due to signals sent from illegal threads):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue, Retry, Worker


class WorkerPool: # TODO: find a better name
    def __init__(self):
        self._queues = {}
        self._worker_procs = []
        self._redis_conn = Redis()

    def __del__(self):
        for proc in self._worker_procs:
            proc.kill()

    def _get_queue(self, name):
        try:
            return self._queues[name]
        except KeyError:
            new_queue = Queue(name, connection=self._redis_conn)
            self._queues[name] = new_queue

            new_worker = Worker([new_queue], connection=self._redis_conn, name=name)
            worker_process = mp.Process(target=new_worker.work)
            worker_process.start()
            self._worker_procs.append(worker_process)

            return new_queue

    def add_job(self, queue, func, *func_args):
        q = self._get_queue(queue)
        job = q.enqueue(func, *func_args, retry=Retry(max=3))
        return job
```

Not sure how good this is, but it seems to do what I want for now

Comment: Probably `mp.Pool` will be easier to control than manually starting each `mp.Process`?

Comment: how can I pool when each process is introduced in a different call?

Comment: With a Pool, you specify a fixed number of processes when you declare it, then give it calls to execute using the `apply_async` method (and friends); those calls will be packed up by the pool and executed in one of the workers — it'll queue them up and dispatch them for you, so you may not even need a queue. See the [Using a pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) examples in the docs.

Comment: An even higher-level abstraction is the `ProcessPoolExecutor` in the [`concurrent.futures` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). That lets you do things like submit a bunch of jobs, then loop through the results on an "[as completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed)" basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need small-scale multiprocessing, tied to one main process, all running on the one machine, take a look at the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and the [`concurrent.futures` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) and their `Pool` and `ProcessPoolExecutor` objects. Unless you have specific requirements, it's probably better to use the `Pool` or `ProcessPoolExecutor` rather than start up `Process` objects manually. (In that case Redis may or may not be overkill.)

If your needs are larger-scale, workers across multiple machines, there's a whole category of software for running these; RabbitMQ is one widely-known one, but it's just one of several, each with its own strengths and weaknesses. Each of the cloud providers (if you're in the cloud) also has its own offering for this functionality. You probably want to read up on the features of several of the off-the-shelf solutions, decide which one is a good match, then set that up.

That said, I have in the past implemented a custom Redis-based queueing system; sometimes you really do need something not provided by any of the existing solutions. In that situation, the design will be heavily influenced by what features you do need. In my case, it was fine-grained priorities...